# Correlation of %VO2max and heart rate

Tags: heart-rate, vo2max

**In training theory, effort is often quantified as %VO2max, whereas another (perhaps more old-school?) measure is %maxHR.**

These two metrics aren't easily convertible. This is because an effort level of 0 equates to 0% VO2max, which, of course, doesn't translate to 0% maxHR.

However, I'm wondering if the following assertion is correct:

0% VO2max corresponds to resting heart rate
100% VO2max corresponds to maximum heart rate

**Given these, could we then state that 50% VO2max is equivalent to 0.5 (maximum heart rate - resting heart rate) + resting heart rate?**

Answer (score 0):

If you search ["vo2 vs heart rate relationship graph"](https://www.google.com/search?q=vo2%20vs%20heart%20rate%20relationship%20graph) on Google images you'll find that the graphs look fairly linear (at least, during exercise). This would indicate that your assertion is correct (or at least approximately so, when exercising).